# Delete Duplicate Rows - Time Out Error With Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a long data sheet where I use this script to delete rows on the basis of column B.

Because of a lot of data I am facing timeout error. How can I change my script to bypass Google Apps Script run limit?

```
function deleteDuplicate() {

   var sheetName = "1hr Data"; // Please set the sheet name.
   var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);

  // get values of column C
  var col = sh.getDataRange().getValues().map(x => x[1]);

  // get indexes of duplicated values in the column
  var duplicates = col.map((x,i) => 
    col.slice(i+1).includes(x) ? i+1 : '').filter(String); 

  // remove rows by the indexes
    duplicates.reverse().forEach(x => { sh.deleteRow(x); SpreadsheetApp.flush() });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The next code works for me fine for 10K rows

```js
function deleteDuplicate() {

  var sheetName = "1hr Data"; // Please set the sheet name.
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);

  // get values of column C
  var col = sh.getDataRange().getValues().map(x => x[1]);

  // get indexes of duplicated values in the column
  var duplicates = col.map((x, i) =>
    col.slice(i + 1).includes(x) ? i + 1 : '').filter(String);

  if (duplicates.length) {

    const requests = duplicates.reverse().map(index => {
      const deleteDimensionRequest = Sheets.newDeleteDimensionRequest();
      deleteDimensionRequest.range = Sheets.newDimensionRange();
      deleteDimensionRequest.range.dimension = 'ROWS';
      deleteDimensionRequest.range.sheetId = sh.getSheetId();
      deleteDimensionRequest.range.startIndex = index - 1;
      deleteDimensionRequest.range.endIndex = index;
      const request = Sheets.newRequest();
      request.deleteDimension = deleteDimensionRequest;
      return request;
    });

    const batch = Sheets.newBatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
    batch.requests = requests;

    Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(batch, SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId());
  }

}
```

You can optimize this. For example, if the lines to be deleted are adjacent.

Note that you must enable the Sheets Advanced Service.

Also there is another approach from @cooper words

```js
function deleteDuplicate1() {
  var sheetName = "1hr Data"; // Please set the sheet name.
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const values = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var col = values.map(x => x[1]);
  const data = values.filter((x, i) => String(col.slice(i + 1).includes(x[1]) ? i + 1 : ''));
  sh.clearContents().getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: unable to find Sheet Advanced Services in App Script

Comment: @ShabnumZaidi, yep. Check this article [Enable advanced services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services) You have to switch on `Sheets API`

Comment: ok I tried both scripts, the first one delete every duplicate, I mean both duplicate values at least I need one value and second code works abruptly delete my header row and put data in it.

Comment: The first code works really fast though, if you can make it delete all duplicate values except the first one.

Comment: Add  `if (duplicates.length > 1) {`. Then write the next line `duplicates.shift();` before the line `const requests = duplicates ...`

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon your spreadsheet.  If you don't use formulas and can tolerate the widespread use of setValues()  then I often keep the rows that I want by storing them in a two dimensional array.  I'll clear the entire data space and replace it with one setValues() which is much faster than deleeting one row at a time.  However, that normally causes problems for people that use cell formulas.  So it depends upon how you use the spreadsheet.

Comment: I do not use any formula. Please can you write the idea in script so I deploy it because I have no programing background that's why unable to write the code by myself.

Comment: I only have to match duplicates in column B and then delete the whole row accordingly.